# Laravel 5.2 how to use config::set in middleware

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I want to use `config::set` in my Middleware for the set the value globally. But it is generating error.

Below is the code which I am using

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = 'admin') {

        if (!Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
            return redirect('/admin/login');
        }

        //dd(Auth::guard('admin')->user()->id);
        $admin = $this->admin->with('adminRole')->find(Auth::guard('admin')->user()->id);
        config::set('bmc.admin_permission', $admin);    

        // check user roles
        if (array_key_exists('0', $admin->adminRole) && isset($admin->adminRole[0]->name)) {
            dd($admin->hasRole($admin->adminRole[0]->name));
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
```

Here is the error which I get

```
Class 'App\Http\Middleware\config' not found
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I never used Config set but since it is a Facade, you have to add `use Config` after your namespace declaration.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose you have a file `config/bmc.php` like:

```
return[
   'admin_permission' => 'initial value'
];
```

and you want to change dynamically `admin_permission` value. You can use laravel global function `config()` like:

```
$settings = [
   'bmc.admin_permission' => 'some value'
];
config($settings);
```

Enjoy coding :)